# Max order for which connected Cayley Graphs are known to be Hamiltonian

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-groups

There is a well-known conjecture that all connected Cayley graphs are Hamiltonian.
For how large a value of n has the conjecture been verified (i.e., for all groups whose order is at most n)?

Comment: Not an answer, but: "[Almost all Cayley graphs are Hamiltonian](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02108156)": Jixiang, Meng, and Huang Qiongxiang. *Acta Mathematica Sinica* **12**.2 (1996): 151-155.

Comment: I think that I did cubic Cayley graphs on up to 1000 vertices quite a few years ago, in the general hope that if any counterexample to the conjecture exists then cubic is the most likely place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to :
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5795v3.pdf 
this is known for all n up to 120 except 72, 96, 108 and 120.

Comment: I've learned this has been checked to 1280 by Potocnik, Spiga and Verret, J. Symbolic Computation 50 (2013) 465-477.

Comment: It has been checked to 1280 that, in the cubic vertex-transitive case, only the four well-known exceptions occur. The question asked for Cayley graphs of arbitrary valency.